# Socrata - SoQL - Query for recent data

Tags: json, rest, socrata

I'm trying to pull data from a variety of Socrata datasets in to a analytic architecture using the REST json API. I would like to find a way to get the new data dropping into the data set since the last request.

My plan at the moment is to use $order and $where with one of the date fields, and then pull a filtered set since the last day every 24-hours.

Are there any examples of ways to use some data math, or is there a better way that I'm missing to get the newest data since the last query?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a link to one of the datasets you're trying to access? I'd be glad to help out with a couple of examples.